# Python urlib and authentication

Tags: python, authentication, urllib

I need help authenticating logging into this site using urllib. I am using python 3, but I'm willing to revert to 2.x. 
This is what I have sofar (basically from the documentation), it gives not errors, but its not logging in.

```
file =open("loggedinsource.html",'wb')

# Create an OpenerDirector with support for Basic HTTP Authentication...
auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm='kalahari.net',uri='https://www.kalahari.net/profile/pipeline/signin.aspx?',user='myuser',passwd='mypass')

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)

# ...and install it globally so it can be used with urlopen.
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
f=urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.kalahari.net/profile/pipeline/signin.aspx?')

page=f.read()
file.write(page);
file.close()
```

I have been struggling with this for ages, any help please.

Comment: We can help with code questions, but not with "struggling". Do you even know that you need basic HTTP auth? Most websites use sessions/cookies ...

Comment: Just tried visiting the URL in the OPs code, and it's using a form to capture user/pass, not HTTP basic auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you are trying to log into is not using HTTP basic auth; it is using a regular HTML form.

If you want to log into something like this, you probably want to look at something like [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea about the need for HTTP Auth or not, pretty new to python and web programming. thanks I will look into mechanize and I heard ClientForm can be useful too.